# Animating the width of a control

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to animate the width of a control(the Rectangle here). This code does animate the width and auto revereses the width back to its original but not if i trigger the animation again midway. In that case the width auto reverses to the width when I retriggered it, never going back to its original width.

And giving the animation a "From" property requires me to remember the original width and it is not runtime width, it just stays being that. Cant find a way to bind to the Rectangle width or something.
Like saying `<DoubleAnimation From="rectangle.Width"/>`

```
    <Style x:Key="animation" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="Blue" Width="500"></Rectangle>
                    </Grid>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                                 To="250" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="True"></DoubleAnimation>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>

        </Setter>

    </Style>
```

I think binding the rectangle element width to the the "From" property in the animation will solve all the problem. Because it will always auto reverse back to that.
Acually I tried `From="{Binding ElementName=rectangle,Path=Width}"`. its a valid xaml code. But after build errors it says
`Error      Cannot freeze this Storyboard timeline tree for use across threads.`

Comment: The Binding wouldn't help, because it would return the actual, animated value of the Width property. Exactly what is used when you don't set From at all.

Comment: @Clemens not setting From just sets the "From" to the width when it starts the animation.

Comment: @Clemens here i left the name of the element a Rectangle to Rectangle with R. make it lower case r at all places  if you were copying code. I fixed it in the edit.

Comment: "*not setting From just sets the "From" to the width when it starts the animation*" - `{Binding ElementName=rectangle, Path=Width}` would provide exactly that, i.e. the currently animated value. As said, the Binding won't help at all.

Comment: @Clemens no. The animation is actually working with no Form. because the From is set only at the start. But bindinng does not even start the app. its an error. maybe because the  binding object will try to change the From while the animation is running.

Comment: The problem is  when i mouse down while the animation is running. that restarts the animation setting the From to the width of the rectangle when the animation was triggered(which is not equal to the main width 500 of the rectangle). aniamtion runs goes to "To" value then auto reverses to that width. not the actual width of the rectangle which is 500. and it stays like that forever. i get it binding is not going to work. but is there a solution..

Comment: You don't seem to understand what I am trying to say. Anyway, see my answer for a working solution.

Comment: @Clemens got it sorry. did not see the answer. when i was replyng. the answer worked thanx.

Comment: @Clemens ok the width here is solved with scale transform hack. But what about other properties like Fill color. Color does not go back to the same. Try animating the Fill with ColorAnimation without the From and a bit longer duration time.

Comment: @Clemens Well i did not ask you about how and why binding wont work. Because i already got that before. I have been saying same what you said about binding. I was asking what is the way around that. How do i make it know what is the original value before starting the animation. Scale did not acutaly animate the width value. It emulated the width or height being added, tricked the eye. I asked in the comment what about the other properties like backcolor. you cant stick a scaling and render transform hack there, can you? So what is the solution.

Comment: @Clemens 0-1-2-3-4-5-4-3 -click- 3-4-5-4-3-2-1-0 is what i want, Not - ...4-3-click-3-4-5-4-3 stops here because started here. And also not- ...4-3-click-0-1-2-3-4-5-4-3-2-1-0( dont want it to restart right away, want it to be seemless) god help us if i get a reply to this.    Initial value 0 should be able to set dynamicaly whatever is the natural initial value of the element. It is subject to change after resizing the window or something.

Comment: @Clemens 0-1-2-3-4-5-4-3-2-1-0 is normal with no click  scenario.

Comment: @Clemens Read above comments with this, What if i did not know in advance. Like something else changed it to something else. I was hoping to treat it like a variable. If not in xaml then with code. adding this with code in the event handler seems like the way to go.But i am very new in this. Since it is a Style. I am having trouble to find out how to do that. Does style have code behind. I think i should want the storyboard and the animation to be crated inside the event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of animation the Rectangle's Width and hence deal with absolute size values, you may better animate a ScaleTransform, e.g. like this:

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="Blue" Width="500"
                   RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform/>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"
                        From="1" To="0.5" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="True"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```